# Can I list my past transactions with the paypal api in node js

Tags: node.js, api, paypal

Because I don't really have access to my online bank account for a while. I wanted to see how much money I have made and how much I gave out and want to create an app to keep track of that.

My problem is my income goes direct into my bank account and my payments are trough PayPal. So my question is how can I get my past PayPal transactions?

I don't really find anything about that and the PayPal Documentation just confuses me

Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 0):

The [Transaction Search API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/transaction-search/) is quite limited in its capabilities and use cases.

Instead, log in to https://www.paypal.com/signin and click on the Reports tab. Use the Activity Download, and choose csv format if desired

Comment: Do you know a way to automate that download, for example everyday?

Comment: Some large merchants can request access to daily reports delivered via SFTP: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/reports/sftp-reports/ , but otherwise no. So it's usually more practical to reconcile monthly or weekly